# Calling Collection#findOne after #insert doesn't find the element

Tags: meteor

My users are observing a very strange, unreproducible behaviour in my Meteor.js application. After several hours of debugging I found the specific lines of code that causes the problem (on the client):

```coffeescript
Articles = new Meteor.Collection("articles")

Articles.insert({name: "..."}, (err, id) ->
  article = Models.Articles.findOne(id)
  console.log("Created - #{err} - #{id} - #{article}")
)
```

Most of the time the output looks as expected, but from time to time `Models.Articles.findOne` doesn't find the created article on the client although it is saved in the database:

```
Created - undefined - 1234 - undefined
```

Do you have any idea why this might happen, and how I could work around this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be a race condition. The callback for insert doesn't guarantee that your pub-sub relationship has finished sending down the article you inserted. It does give you the `_id`, but that's it.